# Outlook on-send add-in is firing twice

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfficeApp
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"
  xsi:type="MailApp">

  <Id>baf2dcf2-21c6-41ac-9c06-1ea235844d9b</Id>
  <Version>3.15.2.7</Version>
  <ProviderName>TeamsAssist</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-us</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="TeamsAssist Notifications" />
  <Description DefaultValue="TeamsAssist On-Send Notifications" />
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/TeamsAssistLogo64x64.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/TeamsAssistLogo128x128.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://cloudassist.co/" />
  
  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://teamsassistoutlookserver.azurewebsites.net</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>

  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="Mailbox" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>

  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/index.html?serverURL=https://teamsassistoutlookserver.azurewebsites.net/" />
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>

  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <!-- On Send requires VersionOverridesV1_1 -->
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Description resid="residAppDescription" />
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <!-- The functionfile and function name to call on message send.  -->
            <!-- In this particular case the function validateBody will be called within the JavaScript code referenced in residUILessFunctionFileUrl. -->
            <FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
              <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateEmail" />
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Urls>
           <!-- The JavaScript code is hosted on a secure and trusted web server. -->
          <bt:Url id="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/index.html?serverURL=https://teamsassistoutlookserver.azurewebsites.net/" ></bt:Url>
        </bt:Urls>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

I have an Outlook on-send add-in that checks a composed email and under certain conditions, blocks it, per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows

Sometimes - and it seems to be when a block condition is *not* found i.e. the email is OK to send - it fires again, which messes up the logic

Cut down here to the minimum ...

```
'use strict'

console.log('\nVersion 3.4')

// entry point function, called 'On Send'; see Manifest(s)
function validateEmail(event) {
    Office.onReady(function (info) {
        let mailboxItem = Office.context.mailbox.item

        mailboxItem.body.getAsync('html', { asyncContext: event }, function (asyncResult) {
            var allowSend = true
            asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: allowSend })
        })
    })

}
```

[image: Console log, showing run twice]

[YouTube clip of "double On-Send](https://youtu.be/nO1pIQ8LiMk)

```html
// TeamsAssist Outlook OnSend App
// Based ***initially*** on https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send
//
//    Date     Who Version  Comment
// ----------- --- -------  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'use strict'

const version = '3.13.1' // see also version in Manifest

// set both to false for Production
const testing = {
    EnableConsoleLog    : true,     // true for detailed console log
    NeverSend           : false     // true to prevent sending, even if no Notification or Block, for testing purposes only
}

if (testing.EnableConsoleLog) console.log('\nVersion (OnSend): ' + version)

// entry point function, called 'On Send'; see Manifest(s)
async function validateEmail(event) {
    // if (testing.EnableConsoleLog) console.log('validateEmail')

    await getEmailProperties()

    user.MailboxItem.body.getAsync('html', { asyncContext: event }, function (asyncResult) {
        // Trim user FirstName, if necessary
        const userFirstName = user.FirstName.length > global.MaxUserFirstNameLength
            ? user.FirstName.substring(0, global.MaxUserFirstNameLength) + ' ...'
            : user.FirstName

        // Define Notification Message
        email.Notification.Message = 'Hi ' + userFirstName + '; a Notification has occurred; this Email is Blocked. Go to TeamsAssist Help to assist you'

        // Trim Message anyway, if necessary
        if (email.Notification.Message.length > global.MaxNotificationMessageLength)
            email.Notification.Message = email.Notification.Message.substring(0, global.MaxNotificationMessageLength)

        OutlookLog('OnSend', email)

        if (email.Notification.Type === 'NoNotification' || !email.IsBlocked) {
            if (testing.EnableConsoleLog) console.log('Send Allowed')
            user.MailboxItem.notificationMessages.removeAsync(global.NotificationMessageID);
            // asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: testing.NeverSend ? false : true })
            asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: true })
        } else {
            if (testing.EnableConsoleLog) console.log('Send Blocked')
            user.MailboxItem.notificationMessages.replaceAsync(global.NotificationMessageID, { type: 'errorMessage', message: email.Notification.Message })
            asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: false })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint in the onSend event handler? Is it called twice?

Comment: Is there any other software like VBA or COM add-ins that could resubmit the item anew? Did you try to remove the async keyword? Does it help?

Comment: Re event hander, yes, it is clearly invoked twice; re removing async, yes did try, no difference and no VBA / COM addins ...

Comment: Is there a chance that two manifest files added pointing to the same web app?

Comment: This shouldn't happen, if you are the only OnSend Add-in. However if there is ANOTHER OnSend Add-in afterward, then if that add-in blocks. Then your add-in will run again, as the email could have changed.

Comment: Also please provide the Platform and Version # that you are on. Otherwise, if you can reduce the repro down to a small add-in, and/or show some relevant code it may help.

Comment: 1) Presumably if I can see just one entry in Integrated apps (Office Admin) then I can't have two Manifests? Is there another way of finding that out? 2) FYI: I debug this App using F12 Developer tools and "console.log", which is how I can clearly see the App running twice 3) Not entirely clear what you mean by Platform / Version - of what? 4) Yes, I think I'll start to strip down the App and chase it that way. Tks all

Comment: Platform mean which type of Outlook you are using, is it web, win32 or mac version?

Comment: Edited to show stripped down code which manifests "send twice" issue, seen in console log, running in Outlook Web

Comment: We are unable to repro the issue at our side. May I know on what surface did you trigger the add-in [Full compose / Pop out]?

Can you please share a video of the bug, so that we can understand the issue better? It will be better if you can share the manifest of the add-in so that we can debug better.

Comment: Video (YouTube) added, also Manifest & cut-down JS; hope this helps as we're really stuck here. Tks

Comment: Can you try disable console logging, and re-execute, normally, without debugger? I've seen quite a few similar issues on github of office-js, and devs actually never gave proper answer (some users told it has something to do with usage of debugger).

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't affect behaviour i.e. still runs twice

Comment: @JohnD Thanks for the details. We are unavailable to launch your add-in. Can you please host it and share it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution to this issue is indeed that there were two deployments; in case this is useful to anyone else; here's a bit more detail: the "double deployment" was *not* visible in M/S 365 / Integrated Apps, as one deployment was made there, but the other was sideloaded, so only appears in Manage Add-ins, within Outlook - AFAIK. This accounts for the observed "double send" behaviour OK; but there is more: I had another deployment, in another Tenant, and this manifested itself with a different error, Outlook: "We're sorry, we couldn't access .... Make sure you have a network connection ...". Confusing. Thanks all for input